# Woocommerce Shipping and Billing Details not showing on order confirmation page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

when I am logged into my dashboard and place a test order all of the information shows. But when placing a live test order only the order details show, the customer details aren't showing...billing, shipping, email, phone.

Any help would be appreciated. Using flatsome Theme with elementor page builder.

not sure what the issue is yet

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello You can fetch order details using order_id and in woocommerce and using below hook you can display it shipping details and billing details 
// You can use below link for fetching order details in woocommerce

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/

function coupon_thankyou($order_id){
// display content as per the need of billing and shipping details
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'coupon_thankyou', 10, 2 );
```